# Stripping down this SVG diagram to be a footprint in KiCad

Tags: pcb, footprint, cad

This is a continuation of this question:
[Trouble finding/creating footprint for a specific switch (SP10T) in KiCAD](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/648684/trouble-finding-creating-footprint-for-a-specific-switch-sp10t-in-kicad)

I have an SVG diagram of a SP10T switch, from which I would like to create a footprint for KiCad:

[image]

I know I have to strip it down and then leave only the leads, and create the footprints. Is there a way to do this quickly,  and which software could I use?

I would be about ready to grab a caliper and do the manual process of measuring it myself (do remember I'm still green). But, unfortunately, I have yet to receive my package... Damn Fed-Ex getting me fed-up.

EDIT:

Anybody else happen to have a footprint of this?

Comment: I recall that I left a comment on the prior question that the basic pcb layout was given in the datasheet page K-6 (PC Mounting section), it contains all the dimensions for the pin locations.  I actually created a footprint, if you want a copy let me know.

Comment: Oh, that's because I actually thought that the datasheet only contained the diagram of *another* specific switch. As it showed 12 leads, whereas the one I ordered had 10 throws. I thought actual routing needs outweigh generality of footprints.

Answer (score 1):

Tempus Nomen, here's the footprint I created.  Do note that I cannot guarantee it matches all your requirements, feel free to make adjustment as needed.  I'll have to check on the best way to send or upload a file here.

Seems that first transfer idea isn't going to work.
I'll look into another file transfer method.

I made a few additional edits to the part since the first go-round. Also notice that I've included more reference lines in the newest design, these should be helpful if you wanted to create any of the other C&K switches from that datasheet.

Newest edit:
Since the library file is quite small I've added it below as a code sample entry. You should only need to copy the text to a file and give it a name with an extension of .mod, (assuming the newer versions of KiCad can still use this format). You then need to add that new file to the list of libraries in your KiCad_PCB design. Let me know if this works.

[image]

.

Below is the small library code for this one footprint/module.

---

```
PCBNEW-LibModule-V1  1/7/2023 12:55:38 AM
# encoding utf-8
Units mm
$INDEX
A11015RNCQ
$EndINDEX
$MODULE A11015RNCQ
Po 0 0 0 15 63B9091C 00000000 ~~
Li A11015RNCQ
Sc 0
AR 
Op 0 0 0
T0 -0.0508 -15.5956 1.524 1.524 0 0.3048 N V 21 N "SW**"
T1 -0.0508 16.0274 1.778 1.778 0 0.381 N V 21 N "A11015RNCQ"
DS 0 0 1.92405 3.33248 0.00762 24
DS 0 0 1.92405 -3.333496 0.00762 24
DS 0 0 -3.8481 0 0.00762 24
DS 10.72388 2.87528 -10.7188 -2.87528 0.00762 24
DS -10.72388 2.87274 10.72388 -2.87274 0.00762 24
DS -7.8486 7.8486 7.8486 -7.8486 0.00762 24
DS -2.87274 10.72388 2.87274 -10.72388 0.00762 24
DS 2.87274 10.72388 -2.87274 -10.72388 0.00762 24
DS -7.8486 -7.8486 7.8486 7.8486 0.00762 24
DC 14.04366 3.7211 14.52626 3.7719 0.8128 21
DC 0 0 13.1064 0 0.4064 21
DC 0 0 11.0998 0 0.00762 24
DC 0 0 0 -3.8481 0.00762 24
$PAD
Sh "1" R 2.2606 2.2606 0 0 3450
Dr 1.4986 0 0
At STD N 00E0FFFF
Ne 0 ""
Po 10.72388 2.87528
$EndPAD
$PAD
Sh "2" C 2.2606 2.2606 0 0 0
Dr 1.4986 0 0
At STD N 00E0FFFF
Ne 0 ""
Po 7.8486 7.8486
$EndPAD
$PAD
Sh "3" C 2.2606 2.2606 0 0 0
Dr 1.4986 0 0
At STD N 00E0FFFF
Ne 0 ""
Po 2.87274 10.72388
$EndPAD
$PAD
Sh "4" C 2.2606 2.2606 0 0 0
Dr 1.4986 0 0
At STD N 00E0FFFF
Ne 0 ""
Po -2.87274 10.72388
$EndPAD
$PAD
Sh "5" C 2.2606 2.2606 0 0 0
Dr 1.4986 0 0
At STD N 00E0FFFF
Ne 0 ""
Po -7.8486 7.8486
$EndPAD
$PAD
Sh "6" C 2.2606 2.2606 0 0 0
Dr 1.4986 0 0
At STD N 00E0FFFF
Ne 0 ""
Po -10.72388 2.87274
$EndPAD
$PAD
Sh "7" C 2.2606 2.2606 0 0 0
Dr 1.4986 0 0
At STD N 00E0FFFF
Ne 0 ""
Po -10.72388 -2.87274
$EndPAD
$PAD
Sh "8" C 2.2606 2.2606 0 0 0
Dr 1.4986 0 0
At STD N 00E0FFFF
Ne 0 ""
Po -7.8486 -7.8486
$EndPAD
$PAD
Sh "10" C 2.2606 2.2606 0 0 0
Dr 1.4986 0 0
At STD N 00E0FFFF
Ne 0 ""
Po 2.87274 -10.72388
$EndPAD
$PAD
Sh "1A" C 2.2606 2.2606 0 0 0
Dr 1.4986 0 0
At STD N 00E0FFFF
Ne 0 ""
Po 2.72034 2.72034
$EndPAD
$PAD
Sh "9" C 2.2606 2.2606 0 0 0
Dr 1.4986 0 0
At STD N 00E0FFFF
Ne 0 ""
Po -2.87274 -10.72388
$EndPAD
$EndMODULE A11015RNCQ
$EndLIBRARY
```

---

Comment: in Kicad 6 you can select everything in FP editor (Ctrl C) and paste into clipboard. This text when inserted will generate the FP and can be shared here.

Comment: @Nedd The code you shared above, KiCad 6.0 can't seem to open. Perhaps the code is for older versions of KiCad. I'll see if I can convert your code to a newer version, or just edit the SVG in Inkscape.

Comment: Btw, how do I add a footprint, without a specific symbol? Can I just use anything that's similar like, say, Connectors_PinHeaders_xxx?

Comment: Sorry if the format I used is old.  Below is a link to a forum that discusses how to load older (Legacy) Mod library files into newer versions of KiCAD Pcb, hope it helps. - To use the foot print in KiCAD Pcb you need to already have a similar component with the same number of pins, then you can can change the Module by selecting the part and using Footprint - Edit Parameters - Change Module(s).   https://www.snapeda.com/questions/question/problems-importing-mod-files-into-kicad/